# How to create .exe setup which can run only on one computer with product key?

Tags: .net

I searched and found about serial key function in User Interface but that's like  crack-able key and like fix pattern.

Is there any other way and can i make like it run only on one computer ?

Comment: I improved your formatting and removed irrelevant tags.  _[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_

Comment: Arguably **too broad**

Answer (score 0):

You can create product key based on Computer Hardware Serial Id. And at install time check if product key matches current hardware id or not.

Look at these: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff541224.aspx and http://www.vcskicks.com/hardware_id.php

Comment: i wanna run on different client machine , how would it will work , I mean if that than even hardware id would be visible also and i cant convince them to run two setup ?

Comment: First time your software runs on a machine will show user the hardware ID. He will then put this id in your website to get product key. Your website will create a product key based on hardware id. User will enter product key in his installed software. Your software,on each run, will check hardware id and product key applied. If both items are fine then allow execution otherwise show Fake serial error and exit.